# Emails rejected: <IP address> listed as abusive but the listed IP address isn't for my SMTP server

Tags: web-hosting, email, shared-hosting

I am using a shared host from JustHost.com that comes with an email service.

When sending an email to some email address using my address myname@mydomain.com, I got a message saying that my email was rejected, as below.

> This is the mail system at host gproxy8.mail.unifiedlayer.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>                The mail system
> ```
>
> : host mail.adfiap.org[203.167.7.69] said: 550-5.5.1
>   Server IP
>       67.222.33.93 listed as abusive. See
>       550-http://spamauditor.org/best-practices/ip-reputation/ for more
>       information.. 550 Protection provided by MagicSpam 2.1-9.1
>       http://www.magicspam.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)

The most important information from the above message is perhaps **Server IP 67.222.33.93 listed as abusive**. The problem is that I don't know where this IP address comes from. The SMTP server I used is just164.justhost.com, which resolves to IP address 173.254.28.164 (as given by [this tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3Ajust164.justhost.com&run=toolpage)).

Could anybody please help me to understand what actually happened and how to resolve this?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!